# Dynamic binding?

Tags: c#, wpf

May be not a right title for the question but I will try to explain:
My TextBox already bound to a property like:

```
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    public string TextVal
    {
        get
        {
             if (View != null)
                  { 
                         return View.Model.TextForValueField;   // other satrts
                   }
                 return defaultModel.TextForValueField;// first start

        set
        {
             .....//some setters logic with View.Model.TextForValueField
        } 
    }
```

When program starts the View is not open so getter binds the value of the field to the value in default model and it is correct, but then , when I open new `View`
my getter correctly returns values from corresponding `View.Model.TextForValueField`  but the field of TextBox on my windows ribbon menu shows the initial value from default model (?) 
Why??
the xaml for binding is :

```
<Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding MyViewModel.TextVal, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Perhaps there is a way to call getter once more when a View starts? Something like "Refresh" for ribbons??

My property changed function

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }
```

Comment: you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interfaces if your properties change programmatically, to update databound GUI controls.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase your question, when `TextForValueField` is changed your `TextBox` (bound to `TextVal`) is not updated, right?

Comment: You are calling your `RaisePropertyChanged` method in `set` accessor, right?

Comment: Not so. When the program starts First time - it show correct values and bound to correct value (the getter was hit at this step). But after this first time - when all menus are already initialized I am opening a NEW View and I think that when this view is opened Menu items are RE-bind to new values automaticly - but there are no success here I have not target the getter once more and field show previous value.

Comment: Yes - RaisePropertyChanged is in set

Comment: I think your viewmodel class should also inherit from related interface as in `MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged` Edit: You also do not need to bind text value in a setter; you can directly bind it and by inheriting the interface, it should automatically be updated.

Comment: Sorry, I have not wrote this- it is already done

Answer (score 1):

When you *forward* Model property via ViewModel property you have to carry on its updates manually.

```
public class Model
{
    public string Property {get; set;}
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public string BindProperty
    {
        get { return modelInstance.Property; }
        set
        {
            modelInstance.Property = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

When you bind to `BindProperty` your view is not *notified* when `Model.Property` gets changed.

One possible solution is to make `Model` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` too and forward that notification. Another (not advised) is bind to `Model.Property` directly (model still has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

```
public class Model: NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _property;
    public string Property
    {
        get { return _property; }
        set
        {
            _property = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModel: NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    public string BindProperty
    {
        get { return modelInstance.Property; }
        set
        {
            modelInstance.Property = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        modelInstance.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
    }

    void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // forward change notification to View
        if(e.PropertyName == "Property")
            OnPropertyChanged("BindProperty");
    }
}

public abstract class NotifyPropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide your code of  OnPropertyChanged function? It seems that my code ever-lasting loop in this function now =(

Comment: See edit. Perhaps you invoke a recursion somehow? You can ask *new question* about that issue, just make sure to prepare question in [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) format.

Comment: ..no this nor save my app. values still frozen - it seems that (may be) something not right with forwarding changes notifications to View in my case

Comment: If you use binding to display value in the View, then `INotifyPropertyChanged` is all you need. WPF will automatically does all update magic. *Frozen* is a wrong word (because there are [Freezable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.aspx)s). It worth to spend your time to prepare mcve sample (you may realize what is the problem yourself when preparing it), so that other people can reproduce the problem and fix it.